# ¿Cómo hacer que un div que tenga posición fixed top sólo cuando la parte superior de la pantalla lo toque?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Abrir el código en pantalla completa!!!**

Quiero conseguir que "EL DIV FLOTANTE" empiece a flotar solamente cuando el lado superior de la pantalla lo toque, antes de ese momento quiero que mi "DIV FLOTANTE" permanezca en su sitio debajo de header.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #444;
}
.header {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.floating {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  right: 0px;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
</style>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <h1>Texto de header</h1>
  <h1>Texto de header</h1>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
<h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
<h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <h1>Ve scrolando hacia abajo</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1>Ahora mira el espacio que esta entre el div y la parte superior de la pagina. Quiero que ese espacio desaparezca!</h1>
  <hr>

</div>
<div class="floating">
  EL DIV FLOTANTE
</div>
```

Quiero que el espacio entre el div flotante y la parte de arriba del navegador sea 0px.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta ni lo que quieres hacer, puedes ser más claro o subir imágenes de referencia de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez He corregido un poco mi ejemplo, ahora se ve mejor. Quiero que el div flotante toque la parte de arriba del navegador. Gracias por tu peticion para especificar.

Comment: Position:sticky;
 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar position relative/absolute  con el contenido de la pág/ contenedor del div . El div flotante(position fixed) debe estar dentro de otro div, el cual es absolute.

Espero que sea de ayuda